# Could a set of function differing in the name depending on the operand types called theoritically statically polymorphic in C language?

Tags: c++, c, oop

Does a set of functions doing exactly one word but differing in the name like `atoi` , `atol`, `atoll` etc called theoretically polymorphic?

For example I have a function say `swap` which needs to operate on different kind of data types. So i have one function/operation for which i have different implementations, but unfortunately because the language does not support using the same function name, to get such functionality i need to make variants `swap_i` , `swap_l`, `swap_f`, `swap_str` etc etc, and have to call them manually depending on the operands.

When designing the code, one would have designed this as one function, with different implementations, which are invoked depending upon the operands. But in this case the programmer instead of the compiler needs to make the static binding of the functions.
If the programmer implemented it in C++ then the design would be the same (as he/she has followed an OOD approach), but in this case the static binding could be done by the compiler without bothering the user.

Now, if in the design approach `swap` was a polymorphic function, will such a difference in C and C++ design implementation will make the difference, so that we cannot call such a C implementation not polymorphic and the C++ implementation polymorphic ?

**EDIT1:**

Another example:

say we send a union with different possible data types packed in  and a structure wrapping it with a variable indicating which component of the union to be used. Then we can use only one function name `swap` without variants. After we receive the structure in the function, we can internally do operations depending on the datatype active in the union

```
  struct _generic {
     int type;
     union {
              int a;
              float b;
              char c;
     } component;
  } variable;

  swap (struct _generic var2, struct _generic var1)
  {
     if (var1.type == INTEGER)
     {
         /* code for integer */
     }
     else if (var1.type == FLOAT)
     {
        /* code for float */
     }
      .
      .
      .
  }
```

In this case we use another way.

Also note the ellipses operator `...` like in `printf` with this also we can get some builtin feature.

The main point is that, C language does not provide direct implementation of OOD s , but can we use the OOD terminology on the implementation on the C implementation, *if* it is designed by following an object oriented design?

Comment: FWIW, C11 introduced [`_Generic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) which in some cases can automate dispatch to type-appropriate implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it is not incorrect, because the polymorphism and other object oriented terminologies are not something which is language dependent, and is a concept. Now, different languages provide different features with which the implementation of an object model is much easier, and some features are only possible which were not possible in other languages.

If one problem was modelled with OOD approach, and the same model is followed to make an implementation with C and C++ keeping the approach identical, where the difference only comes from the limited feature set of the language, and then they are compiled then both generate assembler code. The C++ outputs for a polymorphic function are not polymorphic anymore after it is converted to the asm.

The difference is that C does not provide features to implement OOD as easier as it can be done in C++ or other OOP languages.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the difference were two characters, or three, or ten? Would the different functions be polymorphic? I would say, no, they would not be. So what is special about 1 character?

Comment: The extra letters on the C/C++ functions denote the data types, like, atoi converts a char/string to an integer, atol car/string to long ,etc .. etc.

Comment: @johnathon: The extra letters on the C functions. They are not C++ functions, except to provide for compatibility. Labelling them as C/C++ functions is more than a bit misleading.

Comment: what my point is that, in the object design `swap` is one function which does its job, and because the language do not support it, so the programmer has to make the bindings. So the the functions are polymorphic (statically), but the language does not implicitly support static polymorphism. Do you agree?

Comment: @phoxis No, I don't. C does not support polymorphism for user code, only for its own constructs such as the maths operators. I have to say, I don't see why you care about this.

Comment: i agree with you on C does not support polymorphism. but is say that polymorphism is a concept. So from your point of view after the c++ code gets compiled, the asm generated is also not polymorphic, they do not have polymorphic feature.

Answer (score 2):

It's not polymorphic, because the `swap` function variants cannot have more than one signature. The entire purpose of polymorphism is to limit the maintenance done by the programmer, and thinking of it as just overloading but done by the human is definitely the wrong way of thinking about it. The trick is in the term- "poly" and "morphism". There's nothing multiple about any of these functions- they just happen to provide similar functionality under similar names, and there's no morphing at all between them, so they are most assuredly not polymorphic.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mixing different concepts and languages, and that is a recipe for confusion. What you are calling polymorphic is usually called overloaded in C++: there are different functions that share a name. Polymorphism is usually referred to the property of overriding the behavior of a function in a base class. The function itself will be one with a fixed set of name, arguments and return type (depending on the language there is some space for covariant return types or contravariant arguments).

As to whether it is appropriate to call a manual implementation in C as overloads, I don't think it is. If you extend and abuse the term, you could make it fit, in exactly the same way that you can program object oriented assembler (some assemblers allow you to define structures, you can add addresses to other code symbols as attributes to the structures... does it make that an object oriented assembler?)

Comment: The title does mention *static* polymorphism though.

Comment: It's also perfectly valid to refer to overloading as a form of static polymorphism- which it is. It's just usually called overloading instead, but it *is* polymorphism too.

Comment: i think its not about any language,its about the object oriented design.What i refer is,from the design we see that there is one function say `swap`,but which needs different implementations to work on different objects.Now,a language supports the implementations to have the same name,and the compiler automatically binds the call.Whereas when implementing the *exactly same* object model one user has to bind different *implementations* to the *function* depending on the objects.So the thing is same,only the difference is that the compiler does for one language,and for the other the user does it

Comment: overloading is static polymorphism there is no doubt about it.

Answer (score 0):

C does not exhibit polymorphism. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29  for information on what polymorphism is. For the C functions to be considered even remotely polymorphic the functions would all have to have the same name, but operate on different data types (aka function overloading).

Comment: "C does not exhibit polymorphism"... actually, preprocessor macros exhibit polymorphic properties (as per your definition, one name, operations on multiple types).

Comment: @Tony Delroy technically function overloading is a form of polymorphisim that C does support C does not however support object polymorphisim which was what the OP gave as an example, hence my answer.